# Get the second string of the URI with Perl regex

Tags: regex, apache, perl, substring, uri

I need to get the second part of the URI, the possible URI are:

```
/api/application/v1/method
/web/application/v1/method
```

I can get `"application"` using:

```
([^\/api]\w*)
```

and

```
([^\/web]\w*)
```

But I know is not the best approach, what would be the good way?

Thanks!

Edit: thank you all for the input, the goal was to set the second parte of the uri into a header in apache with rewrite rules

Comment: You tagged this with Perl but is this Perl code? Because in Perl the best way would be with a module, not regex.

Comment: Try `/(?:api|web)/(\w+)/v1/method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general regex (Perl or PCRE syntax) solution would be:

```
^/[^/]+/([^/]+)
```

Each section is delimited with `/`, so just capture as many non-`/` characters as there are.

This is preferable to non-greedy regexes because it does not need to backtrack, and allows for whatever else the sections may contain, which can easily contain non-word characters such as `-` that won't be matched by `\w`.

Comment: While the question is specifically only about a generic path, I think it's still worth commenting that this solution doesn't parse a URI (since they mention it in the title) but rather only a path with forward slashes

Comment: It does not parse any URI: it parses the path component of a URI, as the examples in the OP are.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options that we can do so, not sure which one would be best, but it could be as simple as:

```
\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/.*
```

which our desired output is in the second capturing group `$2`.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/2T7kZA/1/)

#### Example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

main();   

sub main{    
   my $string = '/api/application/v1/method
/web/application/v1/method';
   my $pattern = '\/(.+?)\/(.+?)\/.*';
   my $match = replace($pattern, '$2', $string); 
   say $match , " is a match  ";

}        

sub replace {
   my ($pattern, $replacement, $string) = @_;
   $string =~s/$pattern/$replacement/gee;

   return $string;
}
```

#### Output

```
application
application is a match
```

#### Advice

[zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim) advises that:

> A legitimate approach, notes:
>
> (1) there is no need for the trailing .*
>
> (2) Need /|$ (not just /), in case the path finishes without / (to
>   terminate the non-greedy pattern at the end of string, if there is no
>   /)
>
> (3) note though that /ee can be vulnerable (even just to errors),
>   since the second evaluation (e) will run code if the first evaluation
>   results in code. And it may be difficult to ensure that that is always
>   done under full control. More to the point, for this purpose there is
>   no reason to run a substitution --- just match and capture is enough.

Answer (score 1):

With all the regex, explicitly asked for, I'd like to bring up other approaches.

These also parse only a (URI style) path, like the regex ones, and return the second directory.

- The most basic and efficient one, just [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string on `/`

  ```
  my $dir = ( split /\//, $path )[2];
  ```

  The `split` returns `''` first (before the first `/`) thus we need the third element. (Note that we *can* use an alternate delimiter for the separator pattern, it being regex: `split m{/}, $path`.)
- Use appropriate modules, for example [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI)

  ```
  use URI;
  my $dir = ( URI->new($path)->path_segments )[2];
  ```

  or [Mojo::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Path)

  ```
  use Mojo::Path;
  my $dir = Mojo::Path->new($path)->parts->[1];
  ```

What to use depends on details of what you do -- if you've got any other work with URLs and web then you clearly want modules for that; otherwise they may (or may not) be an overkill.

I've benchmarked these for a sanity check of what one is paying with modules.

The `split` either beats regex by up to `10-15%` (the regex using negated character class and the one based on non-greedy `.+?` come around the same), or is about the same with them.  They are faster than `Mojo` by about `30%`, and only `URI` lags seriously, by a factor of 5 behind `Mojo`.

That's for paths typical for real-life URLs, with a handful of short components.  With only two very long strings (10k chars), `Mojo::Path` (surprisingly for me) is a factor of six ahead of `split` (!), which is ahead of character-class regex by more than an order of magnitude.

The negated-character-class regex for such long strings beats the non-greedy (`.+?`) one by a factor of 3, good to know in its own right.

In all this the URI and Mojo objects were created once, ahead of time.

---

Benchmark code. I'd like to note that the details of these timings are far less important than the structure and quality of code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use URI;
use Mojo::Path;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $runfor = shift // 3;  #/    
#my $path = '/' . 'a' x 10_000 . '/' . 'X' x 10_000;
my $path = q(/api/app/v1/method);    
my $uri = URI->new($path);
my $mojo = Mojo::Path->new($path);

sub neg_cc {
    my ($dir) = $path =~ m{ [^/]+ / ([^/]+) }x;      return $dir; #/
}
sub non_greedy {
    my ($dir) = $path =~ m{ .+? / (.+?) (?:/|$) }x;  return $dir; #/  
}
sub URI_path {
    my $dir = ( $uri->path_segments )[2];            return $dir;
}
sub Mojo_path {
    my $dir = $mojo->parts->[1];                     return $dir;
}
sub just_split {
    my $dir = ( split /\//, $path )[2];              return $dir;
}

cmpthese( -$runfor, {
    neg_cc      => sub { neg_cc($path) },
    non_greedy  => sub { non_greedy($path) },
    just_split  => sub { just_split($path) },
    URI_path    => sub { URI_path($path) },  
    Mojo_path   => sub { Mojo_path($path) },  
});
```

With a (10-second) run this prints, on a laptop with v5.16

```
                Rate   URI_path  Mojo_path non_greedy     neg_cc just_split
URI_path    146731/s         --       -82%       -87%       -87%       -89%
Mojo_path   834297/s       469%         --       -24%       -28%       -36%
non_greedy 1098243/s       648%        32%         --        -5%       -16%
neg_cc     1158137/s       689%        39%         5%         --       -11%
just_split 1308227/s       792%        57%        19%        13%         --
```

One should keep in mind that the overhead of the function-call is very large for such a simple job, and in spite of `Benchmark`'s work these numbers are probably best taken as a cursory guide.

Comment: This is a URL; File::Spec would not be appropriate, but URI and Mojo::URL would.

Comment: @Grinnz nah, apart from dropping the word "URI" they gave us no hints of it, no schema; they ask for regex and all answers, including yours, just parse a path (rightly, as that's all that's given).  Btw. I saw no suitable methods in `URI` (which would be a gross overkill anyway); same with Mojo.  I specifically went out to find something so that I can support use of a module, and ended up with the plain ol' `File::Spec` (somewhat disappointing).

Comment: @Grinnz If you know of a module that parses the "host" path in the context of URI and conveniently, I'll be glad to add it.  (Or if I missed something from `URI`)

Comment: @Grinnz I'm curious, did you notice the last sentence (from the main part) in my answer?  Well, and the first two really -- I spell it out that this is only about parsing a path, no?

Comment: My answer is specifically for a URL path which the OP is clearly asking about. Filesystem paths require the portability provided by File::Spec, such as (most commonly) allowing backslashes to be separators and allowing volume labels on Windows.

Comment: Mojo::Path is specifically for parsing this part of a URL, so could be used for this: `Mojo::Path->new('/api/application/v1/method')->parts->[1]`. For URI you would use path_segments, which starts with an empty one: `(URI->new('/api/application/v1/method')->path_segments)[2]`

Comment: Filesystem paths and URI paths are not generally compatible as the former is system dependent and the latter is not; the module [URI::file](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::file) exists to convert between the two taking the OS into account (with the file: schema of course).

Comment: @Grinnz Ah, OK, you meant the portability point. I was OK with that ... but I did miss `path_segments` (I tried it ... ? .. apparently not well), and I wasn't familiar with `Mojo::Path`.  Will update shortly, thank you.

Comment: From past experience, the slowness of URI is entirely unsurprising.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `([^\/api]\w*)` consists of a capturing group and a negated character class that will first match 1 time not a `/`, `a`, `p` or `i`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0s0Hj/1).

After that 0+ times a word char will be matched. The pattern could for example only match a single char which is not listed in the character class.

What you might do is use a capturing group and match `\w+`

```
^/(?:api|web)/(\w+)/v1/method
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:api|web)` Non capturing group with alternation. Match either api or web
- `(\w+)` Capturing group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `/v1/method` Match literally as in your example data.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQZX5I/1)